# Launchpad pull request

Tags: bazaar, pull-request, launchpad

I want to propose a change to the source code of a project which is hosted in Launchpad.

Problem is: I have no idea how to use the bazaar version control system, and I've never used Launchpad, so what are the equivalent steps of making a Github pull request, but applied to this system?

I have read some tutorials, and they are insanely long and not very straightforward, for something that should be really simple.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Alright, no need to read a [doctoral thesis](http://www.joinfu.com/2008/08/a-contributors-guide-to-launchpadnet-part-2-code-management/) about it, or [single documentation chapters](https://dev.launchpad.net/UsingMergeProposals) that lack details about the [bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/) VCS that you don't know (or don't care to know).

This is the definitive and simplest step-by-step guide (especially for devs already used to the git/github workflow):

### Your target project is https://launchpad.net/foo, clone it:

```
bzr init-repo foo
```

(creates directory "foo" which will have all our branches of the repo)

```
cd foo 
bzr branch lp:foo/trunk trunk # if this fails, visit https://launchpad.net/foo/trunk
```

(clone the 'master' branch into the "trunk" folder)

```
bzr branch trunk fixicate-the-bar-to-do-baz
```

(creates a feature branch locally)

```
cd fixicate-the-bar-to-do-baz
```

(now you can make your changes)

```
bzr add some_new_file.bla some_new_folder.dir
```

(if you need to add newly created files/dirs to the commit; no need to do this for modified ones)

```
EDITOR=nano bzr commit --fixes lp:99999
```

(if your favourite editor is "nano" and if you are fixing a launchpad bug, number 99999, with the commit)

### Propose the pull request (or '*merge-request*', in the launchpad dialect):

```
bzr push lp:~usernameinlaunchpad/foo/fixicate-the-bar-to-do-baz
```

(to push your branch remotely to your launchpad code forks)

```
https://code.launchpad.net/~usernameinlaunchpad/foo/fixicate-the-bar-to-do-baz/+register-merge
```

(the URL to direct your browser to propose your change upstream)

**IMPORTANT!**: In the last step (when you're creating the merge-request in that webpage), expand the "Extra options" element, and fill in the commit message (even if it says "optional", and even if you already added a commit message when doing `bzr commit`), otherwise the Ubuntu Jenkins Bot will revert your commit after it gets merged.

### About the review process:

You will get an email when there is a review from any person. 
But beware, it's not enough that a maintainer marks your patch as **Review: Approve**. The merge-request's status needs also to change from **Needs review** to **Approved**. And you will get both changes in separate e-mails. Don't hesitate to bother the maintainer about doing **both** changes, not just the first, otherwise your merge-request will sit as approved forever, without being merged by the launchpad bots.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to do this in a more straightforward way for http://launchpad.net/ubuntu-dev-tools:

```
bzr branch lp:ubuntu-dev-tools   # git clone ...
cd ubuntu-dev-tools
...
bzr launchpad-login techtonik
bzr commit
bzr push lp:~techtonik/ubuntu-dev-tools/minor-python3-fix
```

Went https://code.launchpad.net/~techtonik/ubuntu-dev-tools/minor-python3-fix and hit "Propose for merging". Here is [the result](https://code.launchpad.net/~techtonik/ubuntu-dev-tools/minor-python3-fix/+merge/247538).

Comment: I got "bzr: ERROR: Transport operation not possible: http does not support mkdir()"